# How do you full text search in an amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, full-text-search, amazon-emr

What are options to create solution based on the AWS native platform to be able to full text search in an amazon s3 bucket/s.

We have process that will be storing daily 100+ of text files ranging from 100K to 150 MB that we need to retain for 1-2 years. We want to have an ability to be able to full text search.

Comment: Ship the text stored in the files to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon S3 management console does not search *inside* objects. It is purely filtering on the filename ("Key") of the objects in the bucket.

If you wish to search inside objects, then you will need to implement other services such as [Amazon Kendra](https://aws.amazon.com/kendra/) or Elasticsearch that will read and index objects.

Amazon S3 is a "Simple Storage Service". It provides highly scalable and reliable storage, but any higher-level functions such as search need to be implemented "on top" of S3. Just think of S3 as a huge, amazingly powerful hard disk that is connected to the Internet. (Sort of.)

Comment: Thanks John for your suggestion. Amazon Kendra seems to be expensive option, As this use case will have less than 100 search a day but will have 100s of thousands of file over time. Basically lot of indexing but less search as search is only used in case of unusual pattern for research purpose.